# How to graph hourly events recorded over months?

Tags: excel, time, graph, analysis

I have been recording my internet speeds over the last few months (damn ISP) and now I'd like to be able to visualize the recorded data but I'm having a very hard time doing so. Any suggestions?

Columns:

`|  day/time  |  ping  |  download  | upload  |`

I can plot each data column (ping, download, upload) over time but the graph becomes too crowded. Is there an automatic way to get averages per day/week? Similar to how Google Analytics handles graphs.
What about stacking the data? For example to compare a month over another. Would this have to be done manually?
Is there any software that could handle these different analysis automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: Those are like 10 questions inside one question..

Comment: since you tagged `excel`, you can use formulas to summarize the data however you want, then make graphs to plot the results how you like as well

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, true, I guess I'm trying to avoid doing all the manual work. It seems like something that could/should be automatized.

Comment: I'd suggest [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) - it's a library to do this kind of timeseries analysis using Python. You could use `ts = read_csv ...` to load from CSV, `ts.resample('5min').mean()` to take an average of 5 minutes of results, then `ts.plot()` to visualise. Happy to demo if you share your data?

Answer (score 0):

So far the only software that seems would be able to handle this kind of heavy analysis is Google's [Data Studio 360](https://www.google.com.pe/analytics/360-suite/data-studio/).

Unfortunately I can't test it as I'm living in Peru and it won't let me try it out over here...